# PostgreSQL server failed to start in Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cloud9-ide

I'd like to setup postgresql for my rails app in **Cloud9**.

The following error was displayed after changing some file.

```
sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2016-04-09 23:49:54 UTC LOG:  invalid connection type "PostgreSQL"
2016-04-09 23:49:54 UTC CONTEXT:  line 1 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf"
2016-04-09 23:49:54 UTC FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
   ...fail!
```

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host:     localhost
  username: ubuntu
  password: password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/**pg_hba.conf**

```
PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
...

# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   localhost            postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             ubuntu                                    peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
...
```

It would be appreciated if you could advise me on how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably due to an invalid entry in the config file. Try reloading it by using

```
pg_ctl reload -D $PGDATA
```

Also assumes that you have the `gem 'pg'` in your gemfile

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Abhilash. Although I tried this command, the following error was appeared. `bash: pg_ctl: command not found` And I have `gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.2'` in my gemfile.

Comment: maybe you need to initialize the directory..For that you can try `initdb ~/.postgres` and `pg_ctl -D ~/.postgres start` ..But I never had to do it with cloud9 before...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Abhilash. No error is displayed after remove 1st line in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`.